# Форма регистрации с двумья значениями

Tags: php, javascript, html, form

Столкнулся с проблемой:

На сайте в форме регистрации есть поле, в которое нужно ввести email (например: exemple@gmail.com) или имя пользователя (например: user_name1).

Вопрос: как в php файле оброботчике формы узнать что именно пришло в переменной `$_POST['login']` - email пользователя или его username?

Comment: зачем его на что-то проверять? смотри просто есть в бд или нет

Comment: Если в логинах у вас запрещены собачки, то вам пришел email при наличии собачки ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой вариант — действительно, сделать запрос который будет искать по обоим значениям. Не знаю, какой query-builder у вас используется (и используется ли).

Как чисты sql это выглядит следующим образом:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '{login}' OR email='{login}') AND 'password' = '{password_hash}'
```

В большинстве штатных случаев этого варианта будет более чем достаточно.

Самая сложное в этом запросе при использовании конкретного query-builder - это найти, каким образом группировать условия в скобки

Answer (score 0):

Проверить регулярным выражением. Например так:

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+$/i", $_POST['login']) == 1) {
 //email
} else {
 //username
}
```

Если же требуется проверка E-Mail адресов потенциально содержащих символы алфавита отличного от английского, то можно воспользоваться способом о котором писал выше `Visman`.

```
if (strpos($_POST['email'], "@") != false) {
 //email
} else {
 //username
}
```

Но данный способ не гарантирует того что вам прислали именно E-Mail адрес.

Comment: А домены давно уже могут быть на языках отличных от английского ;)

Comment: @Visman, вы ошибаетесь, ибо .рф есть : англ символы. `xn--e1afmkfd.xn--p1ai`, что расшифровывается как: `пример.рф`

Comment: @And, я не ошибся. Ни один нормальный человек не будет набирать такую билибеду вручную с клавиатуры :)

Comment: @Visman, ну это только такие люди, которые просто вбивают в поле или в адресную строку. Я говорю в общем плане, когда это происходит на стороне клиента или сервера, где русские домены не будут поддерживаться и нужно будет использовать `punycode` - паникод.